# Mysql - Copying a null value into a not null table

Tags: mysql, null, notnull

There is probably a simple and straight forward answer to this but I'm slightly confused as to what is happening.

I have two basic tables with one column each having the following properties for the column in that table

```
CREATE TABLE test (correct_time timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL)
CREATE TABLE test2 (correct_time timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

I then insert a `NULL` value into `test` i.e.

```
INSERT INTO test ( correct_time ) VALUES (NULL)
```

Now I try and copy all the entries from `test` into `test2`.

```
INSERT INTO test2 SELECT * FROM test
```

This produces a result into `test2`, where the value is now `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

My first question is, the default value of `test2` is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, so why is the `null` value given a value of `0000-00-00 00:00:00`, rather than the most recent time?

Also, this produces a warning, `column 'correct_time' cannot be null`. So if we are inserting a `NULL` value why does it be set to `0000-00-00 00:00:00` rather than throwing an error.

Comment: This may be dependant on the system variable you have set for `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp` in MySQL
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp

Comment: In addition, you need to verify if you have MySQL in `strict` mode or not - this can affect how it handles a `null`, as certain settings will covert a `null` into an empty string, thus `000-00-00 00:00:00`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. This variable was enabled, however once I disabled it the behaviour of the data type timestamp changed.

Answer (score 0):

> My first question is, the default value of `test2` is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, so why is the `null` value given a value of `0000-00-00 00:00:00`, rather than the most recent time?

This is because, default value is used when there is no value being inserted into that column. Here it selects the `null` value from `test.correct_time` and tries to insert into `test2.correct_time`.

> Also, this produces a warning, `column 'correct_time' cannot be null`. So if we are inserting a `NULL` value why does it be set to `0000-00-00 00:00:00` rather than throwing an error.

The warning is because the type of data being inserted des not match the type of the column. This is also the reason why the value is set to `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

To understand this, try this:

```
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES ()
```

This should store the default value.

I'm assuming you have more columns in the tables. You could run the query twice like this:

```
INSERT INTO test2 (SELECT * FROM test WHERE correct_time IS NOT NULL)
INSERT INTO test2 (SELECT column1, column2 FROM test WHERE correct_time IS NULL) -- select all columns except correct_time
```

Comment: I understand that its an invalid type trying to be entered into the column, however when I try to insert a null entry directly into test2 i.e. Insert into test2 values (NULL) , it throws an error. I know it throws an error because we specify to not insert nulls but it null not understood as an invalid type and therefore should be inserted as "0000-00-00 00:00:00" rather than throwing an error?